# Toggle between showing and hiding text (javascript)

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle, show-hide

I have an html-document with 4 `<p>`-tags in the body. I have a separate js-file and want to use javascript to:

- Create and put links in the 1st and 3rd paragraphs.
- Create a function that toggles between showing and hiding the text in
  the paragraph below each link when  the corresponding link is
  activated. The paragraphs should be hidden from the start.

I can't get the toggle function to work. The page still displays all paragraphs from the start and when I click the links the page just flickers for a millisecond.

Below is my code. I'm a beginner and I know it is bad code but I just want it to be a working script. I can't figure out why it doesn't work so would greatly appreciate some help from someone who is good at this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title></title>

 </head>  
 <body>
 <p>When this link is activated..</p>
 <p id="displayPara">..I want this hidden paragraph to be revealed.</p>
 <p>And if the link below is clicked..</p>
 <p>..this paragraph should be revealed.</p>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="showHide.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>


         The JS-file:
//Creates the 2 links and puts them where I want them in the document body.
function Links() {                                          
        a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href", "showHide.html");
        a.setAttribute("id", "firstLink");                             
        a.innerHTML = "<br></br>Show paragraph";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].appendChild(a);

        a2 = document.createElement("a");
        a2.setAttribute("href", "showHide.html");
        a2.setAttribute("id", "secondLink");                        
        a2.innerHTML = "<br></br>Show paragraph";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].appendChild(a2);

    }
    Links();

    /*I want this function to toggle between showing and hiding the 2nd and 4th paragraphs when the links are clicked. 
    I tried with the first link first and it doesn't work.*/
    a.onclick = function toggle() {
         displayPara = document.getElementById("displayPara");
         firstLink = document.getElementById("firstLink");
        if(displayPara.style.display == "block") {
                displayPara.style.display = "none";
            firstLink.innerHTML = "Show paragraph"
        }
        else {
            displayPara.style.display = "block";
            firstLink.innerHTML = "Hide paragraph";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<br>` is an empty tag, `</br>` is an apparition that is ignored. The *title* element must not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

This is not XML, there are no short tags. Use:

```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
```

The *title* element must have content:

```
   <title>Show Hide</title>
```

In the script:

```
//Creates the 2 links and puts them where I want them in the document body.
function Links() {
```

Function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. Also, a function's name should hint at what it does, so:

```
function addLinks() {

        a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href", "showHide.html");
        a.setAttribute("id", "firstLink");
```

Instead of using *setAttribute*, it's more convenient to set properties directly:

```
    a.href = 'showHide.html';
    a.id = 'firstLink';
```

Presumably *shoeHide.html* is the name of the HTML file your code is in. So when the link is clicked, the page reloads. Rather than using a link, which looks to the user like it should go to another page, you should use a button, which indicates that something will happen but likely not take the user anywhere. It also doesn't require a *href* attribute.

As Lior said, clicking on the link will reload the page, so whatever modifications the script might do, they are irrelevant since the original page is then reloaded.

```
        a.innerHTML = "<br></br>Show paragraph";
```

The BR element is empty, it has no content and no closing tag, so:

```
        a.innerHTML = "<br>Show paragraph";
```

But since I've suggested using a button instead, consider:

```
    var a = document.createElement('input');
    a.type = 'button';
    a.className = 'openCloseButton';
    a.value = 'Show paragraph';
```

and rename the function addButtons. Then there's:

```
       document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].appendChild(a);
```

Which is fine. Since you want an identical button on another P, you can clone the one you just made:

```
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].appendChild(a.cloneNode());
```

The buttons don't need an ID. But you might consider giving the paragraphs that need buttons a class so you can access them by *className* like the buttons below.

```
    }
    Links();
```

Now for the toggling code. You can get the buttons using their class:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.openCloseButton');
```

Now add the same listener to each:

```
for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {
```

Now for the attachment.

```
    a.onclick = function toggle() {
```

There is no need to give function expressions a name. They are only there so the function can be referenced from inside the function (they're also handy for debugging). Some versions of IE create named function expressions as global functions, so best not to give them names unless you have a really good reason to do so.

```
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
```

Now comes the tricky part, how to reference the related paragraph to hide or show? The paragraph of interest is the one that is the next sibling of the paragraph that the button is in, which is a bit tricky. You should carefully consider the DOM layout before doing this as any change to the structure will break your function. So split out a function to get the next paragraph sibling that might look like:

```
function getNextParaSibling(el) {
  var next;

  // Search siblings until a P is found
  while (el.nextSibling) {
    next = el.nextSibling;
    if (next.tagName && next.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p') {
      return next;
    }
    el = next;
  }
  // If a next sibling P isn't found, return null
  return null;
}
```

So now in the main function...

```
    displayPara = getNextParaSibling(this.parentNode);
```

And because you can't be certain that worked, deal with it missing:

```
    if (!displayPara) return;
```

Now if the element has been hidden using CSS, that will not be reflected in the element's own *style.display* property. So you can use *computedStyle*, but then you don't know how to set it. So things are messy. In that case, it's much better to hide and show the element by using a class, then you just add or remove the class. You should have some library functions to help with that, but for now you can assume that the elements only have one class. So assume there is a class like:

```
.hideMe {display: none;}
```

and you add that to the paragraphs to be hidden like:

```
<p class="hideMe" ...>
```

then you can do:

```
    // If element is hidden
    if (displayPara.className == 'hideMe') {
      displayPara.className = '';
    } else {
      displayPara.className = 'hideMe';
    }
```

and you're done. In summary, the HTML can be:

```
<p>When this link is activated..</p>
<p class="hideMe">..I want this hidden paragraph to be revealed.</p>
<p>And if the link below is clicked..</p>
<p class="hideMe">..this paragraph should be revealed.</p>
```

and the script:

```
function addButtons() {
  var a = document.createElement('input');
  a.type = 'button';
  a.className = 'openCloseButton';
  a.value = 'Show paragraph';
  document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].appendChild(a);
  document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].appendChild(a.cloneNode());
}
addButtons();

function getNextParaSibling(el) {
  var next;

  // Search siblings until a P is found
  while (el.nextSibling) {
    next = el.nextSibling;
    if (next.tagName && next.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p') {
      return next;
    }
    el = next;
  }
  // If a next sibling P isn't found, return null
  return null;
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.openCloseButton');
for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
  displayPara = getNextParaSibling(this.parentNode);

  if (!displayPara) return;

    // If element is hidden
    if (displayPara.className == 'hideMe') {
      displayPara.className = '';

    } else {
      displayPara.className = 'hideMe';
    }
  }
}
```

though all of it should be run from inside an immediately invoked function expression (aka IIFE).